# Unable to connect Apache Zeppelin with DSE Cassandra Analytics nodes

Tags: apache-spark

Environment details:

a) Dse version 5.0.1 + Spark 1.6.1 + spark-cassandra-connector_2.10-1.6.0.jar

b) Apache Zeppelin (zeppelin-0.6.0-dse-5.0.0-5.0.1.tar).

Error: able to connect to Cassandra. however when trying to run notebook with spark interpreter facing guava jar issue. any suggestion please to solve this

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Detected Guava issue #1635 which indicates that a version of Guava less than 16.01 is in use.  This introduces codec resolution issues and potentially other incompatibility issues in the driver.  Please upgrade to Guava 16.01 or later.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to your Spark folder, you should go to `$SPARK_HOME/jars` and find `guava_14.0.1.jar` and replace it with guava 16.01. You can download guava 16.01 from [maven repository](http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/16.0.1/guava-16.0.1.jar)

After you replace dependency problem should disappear.
Make sure your application doesn't transitively depend on older versions of guava